# Formal Power Series Problem5

Tags: combinatorics

I want to prove the following.

Let $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ be formal power series.

(a) Show that if $A(x)B(x)=0$ then $A(x)=0$ or $B(x)=0$

(b) Show that if $A(x)^2=B(x)^2$ then $A(x)= \pm B(x)$

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of ring is the coefficient ring, a field?

Answer (score 1):

For a) consider the product of two non-zero series and look what happens to the lowest non-zero terms.

For b) recall $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ and use a).

(The answer assumes you have no zero-divisors in the base field/ring where the claim is also false; yet it works for real, complex, integeral etc.)